# Students of the Chazon Ish

Tags: chazon-ish, rebbe-talmid-muvhak

Were there any living students of [R. Avraham Yeshaya Karelitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avrohom_Yeshaya_Karelitz) on April 8, 2015, 20 *Nisan*, 5775?

Comment: I was unaware that the Chazon Ish gave regular shiurim like roshei yeshiva. As far as people who learned a lot of Torah from him we have Rav Chaim Kanuevsky and Rav Shteinman.

Comment: @Yoni I dont think I implied anywhere that the Chazon Ish gave regular shiurim like roshei yeshiva. To what degree did rabbis Kanievsky and Shteinman interact with him?

Comment: [R' Chaim Greinman z"l](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/boruch-dayan-emmes/299285/petira-of-hagaon-harav-chaim-shaul-greinaman-zatzal.html).

Answer (score 8):

[Rav Chaim Kanievsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Kanievsky) - Nephew

[Rav Yitzchak Abadi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchak_Abadi)

[Rav Nissim Karelitz](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissim_Karelitz) - Nephew

[Rabbi Dr. Zvi A. Yehuda](http://torahinmotionusa.org/users/rabbi-dr-zvi-yehuda)

[Rav Meir Tzvi Bergman](http://www.chareidi.org/archives5764/LCH64features.htm)

Rav Yechiel Michel Zacharish

[Rav Chaim Greineman] he was alive at the time of the OPs questions)[6](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/boruch-dayan-emmes/299285/petira-of-hagaon-harav-chaim-shaul-greinaman-zatzal.html)

[Rav Ahron Leib Shteinman זצ"ל](http://m.jpost.com/Israel-News/OBITUARY-Rabbi-Shteinman-Haredi-leader-of-the-generation-dies-at-104-517796/amp) (he was alive at the time of the OPs questions)

Comment: Some of the rabbis here were around 20 y.o. when the CI died. Just saying. And R. Abadi, while it’s “known” that he was a student of CI, I always wondered *how much* of a student he could have been since in his teenage years he was a student at Chevron and it’s not like CI was actively running a yeshiva with students having access to him at any given time. Additionally, he too was all of twenty years when CI died. As an aside, R. Abadi only calls R. Aaron Kotler “*mori ve’rabbi*”.

Comment: @Oliver he was a very real student, and he was sent by the CI to learn in Lakewood. There are very few things that are agreed upon regarding R Abadi, this is one of them. I have no agenda here

Comment: My comment wasn’t directed at you or your [non-]agenda. It’s just a critical observation to bring to readers’ attention. To the contrary, shedding light on R. Abadi’s time as a student under CI would be appreciated and, needless to say, insightful.

Comment: @Oliver understood